# Using Etag for Optimistic locking in Azure Blob Storage not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

In the following example, I'm trying to use etags from a Blob Container to ensure I'm not overwriting a value. I expect the second call to `SetMetaDataAsync` to fail since I'm using the same etag as the original request, but the second request is made successfully. I've verified that the etag did change after the first request by looking in the portal.

Why is the second value overwriting the first value when it submits an incorrect etag?

```
var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("random-test");

container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
container.FetchAttributesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var etag = container.Properties.ETag;

container.Metadata["test"] = "foo";
container.SetMetadataAsync(AccessCondition.GenerateIfMatchCondition(etag), new BlobRequestOptions(), new OperationContext() { }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

//uses the same etag as the first request but the etag on the container has changed now.
container.Metadata["test"] = "bar";
container.SetMetadataAsync(AccessCondition.GenerateIfMatchCondition(etag), new BlobRequestOptions(), new OperationContext() { }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this article:

- [Specifying Conditional Headers for Blob Service Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Specifying-Conditional-Headers-for-Blob-Service-Operations?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Subheading2)

The `Set Container Metadata` operation only support `If-Modified-Since` conditional header.

Answer (score 3):

## Azure Storage SDK v12

NuGet: `Azure.Storage.Blobs`

```cs
BlobClient blobClient = ...;

try {
    var existingProperties = await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
    var etagCondition = new BlobRequestConditions() {
        IfMatch = existingProperties.Value.ETag
    };

    await blobClient.UploadAsync(content, conditions: etagCondition);
} catch (RequestFailedException ex) when (ex.ErrorCode == BlobErrorCode.ConditionNotMet) {
    // Todo: handle ETag mismatch
}
```